# Can `cat` show files using code markup in colors?

Tags: colors, cat

Sometimes I quickly want to view the contents of a file from the command line. For this I of course use [`cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29), but it is often source files in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) or simple [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). For these files it would be handy if `cat` could give some color markup to the files, so that it reads more easy.

Can `cat` do such a thing?

Comment: This may already have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855793/2943276)

Comment: ha @wilf I found the same code with google :D Also worth noting this topic on SO: http://superuser.com/questions/84426/are-there-any-options-to-let-cat-output-with-color

Comment: @Rinzwind - I searched stackoverflow , as it was bound to come up ;-)

Comment: This question reminds me of [`cat -v` considered harmful](http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`cat` is not able to do this. However, maybe [pygments](http://pygments.org/) may be able to help you there. It is a python script and can be either installed via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```

or easily downloaded and installed via easy_install.

It supports lots of source code [languages](http://pygments.org/languages/) and also markup languages

It is used by

```
pygmentize -g <filename>
```

Comment: Open file as `pygmentize -g <filename>`, the `-g` switch is important to handle file without lexer. for example if you try `/etc/fstab` to open without `-g` it will fail.

Comment: Thanks @souravc Added it to the answer. Interestingly, this argument does not seem to be mentioned in the man page or help page

Comment: Well I played a lot with it. you can find it, try `pygmentize --help` 

If `-g` is passed,
attempt to guess the lexer from the file contents, or pass through as
plain text if this fails (this can work for stdin).

Comment: This is the best, then alias cat to pygmentize -g and you are golden. In fish it is simple as `funced cat... type pygmentize -g $argv... save..funcsave cat`.

Comment: in my `bashrc` I added:   `command -v pygmentize >/dev/null 2>&1 && alias cat='pygmentize -g'`

Comment: This is surely going to cause trouble when you run something needing 'accurate cat', eg filecopies.. Why not use 'pcat' for the highlit output? ('ccat' exists!)

Comment: How can we change its color theme?

Answer (score 19):

Not from `cat` itself but you can use something like [source highlite](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/)  or [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/) or [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php)

> **Source-highlight**
>
> This program, given a source file, produces a document with syntax highlighting. It also provides a C++ highlight library (new) (since version 3.0).
>
> Source-highlight reads source language specifications dynamically, thus it can be easily extended (without recompiling the sources) for handling new languages. It also reads output format specifications dynamically, and thus it can be easily extended (without recompiling the sources) for handling new output formats. The syntax for these specifications is quite easy (take a look at the manual).
>
> The manual about installation:
>
> See the file INSTALL for detailed building and installation instructions; anyway if you're used to compiling Linux software that comes with sources you may simply follow the usual procedure, i.e., untar the file you downloaded in a directory and then:

```
 cd <source code main directory>
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

> **Supercat**
>
> This is Supercat's homepage. Supercat is a program that colorizes text based on matching regular expressions/strings/characters. Supercat supports html output as well as standard ASCII text. Unlike some text-colorizing programs that exist, Supercat does not require you to have to be a programmer to make colorization rules.
>
> If you have written a supercat config file for a standard file type please do not hesitate to contact me at "bug-spc (at) nosredna (dot) net" for possible inclusion in the supercat distribution.
>
> - [Here is an example page](http://supercat.nosredna.net/html-example-spc.html) of Supercat's work on Gentoo's emerge.log
> - [Installation/source file (tar.gz)](http://supercat.nosredna.net/supercat-0.5.5.tar.gz)
> - [Example configuration file](http://supercat.nosredna.net/spcrc-emerge)

Or with a **function** ([source](http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/programmer/syntax-highlighting-in-terminal/)):

```
#!/bin/bash#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -t 0 ];then
        file=/dev/stdin
elif [ -f $1 ];then
        file=$1
else
        echo "Usage: $0 code.c"
        echo "or e.g. head code.c|$0"
        exit 1
fi
pygmentize -f terminal -g $file
```

Requires: [Pygments](http://pygments.org/download/)  (`sudo apt-get install python-pygments python3-pygments`)
  Add it as a function to bash .functions and give it a name like color()

Comment: It works much slower  than `cat` , would it be possible to make it faster?

Answer (score 16):

As from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799752/2943276), you can use the `python-pygments` packages to highlight stuff. First do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygments python3-pygments
```

then:

```
pygmentize -g FILENAME
```

then have a go:

[image]

You can also set it as an alias, like in the answer I linked - basically, run this:

```
echo "alias catc='pygmentize -g'" >> ~/.bash_aliases 
chmod +x ~/.bash_aliases
```

Close the terminal, open it again, and the `catc` command should now work - if it does not, make sure these lines are in the `.bashrc` file, and are uncommented:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

---

Another thing would be to just use `nano`:

```
nano testfile
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`man view` or `man vim`

Basic usage: `view <filename>`

Quit: `:q<Return>` (add an `<Esc>` first if using `vim`), or `ZZ` (upper case z twice).

The programmer's text editor `vim` has all you need already, and is likely already part of your system.

`vim` has a read-only mode activated with `view` or `vim -R`. If all you want to do is view the marked-up file, it should be enough.

Simple to use, navigable, available everywhere. No need to mess about with installing new software or writing bash scripts.

Comment: I know. The thing is that openeing and closing VIM is not quick. I want to instantly view a file and then continue on the command line. That's why I found pygmentize such a good one. Instant result, no quiting a program or anything.. :)

Comment: @kramer65 OK of course it's your preference, but you don't need to "open" `vim` or `view`, you just provide it with the file: `view file.py`, so no difference there with `cat`. Sure you need to close it, but really, `:q<Return>` or `ZZ` are not difficult tasks.

Comment: The major problem being that vi/vim/view don't write to stdout, so I can't easily write a command whilst glancing at the syntax highlighted output above.

Answer (score 4):

One can check out [ccat](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat).

It adds syntax highlight to output files.

Answer (score 4):

## Bat —  A cat clone with wings

You might also want to check out [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) which has the following features:

- Syntax highlighting
- Git integration
- Optionally showing non-printable characters
- Automatic paging with `less`
- File concatenation as a drop-in replacement for `cat` when redirected

### Preview

[image: Screenshot of bat showing a colored file]

*Picture taken from [the official GitHub](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat)*

### Installation

You can get the latest Debian package [here](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases) and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i bat_0.10.0_amd64.deb
```

Adapting the version number and architecture.

Answer (score 3):

`cat` can not produce syntax highlighting solely. Still you can do this as follows, using `python-pygments`. First install it from terminal as,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```

Now copy the function below `~/.bashrc`. It will give you what you want **moreover it will preserve the properties of `cat`** otherwise there is no point of using `cat`

```bsh
catc(){
    cat "$@" > /tmp/.tmp
    pygmentize -g /tmp/.tmp
    rm /tmp/.tmp
}
```

Source `~/.bashrc` as,

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

It will give colourized output,

```
catc <filename>
```

It will concatenate with color as well,

```
catc <file1> <file2> ... <filen>
```

Comment: Is there a way to enable scrolling with up and down arrows when using  `pygmentize?`  I'm opening it using a command of the form `xterm -e "pygmentize -g <filename>"`  and am finding that the only way to scroll is to use the scroll bar.     I tried piping the output to `less` but that resulted in garbage output.

Comment: yes you can use `pygmentize` with less.  Create a bash function `lessc` as following: `lessc () 
{ 
    pygmentize -gf terminal "$1" | less -R
}`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers cover why `cat` is not able to do it. Though you can do it with less using
[lesspipe.sh](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/lesspipe.html).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than installing a third party package, you can simply use `gedit` to quickly view a file with syntax highlighting. For example copy the address bar above and paste into your terminal:

```
gedit https://askubuntu.com/questions/405960/can-cat-show-files-using-code-markup-in-colors
```

You will see this question in HTML with formatted colors:

[image: gedit https.png]

- You can use familiar `gedit` navigation keys
- You can turn line wrap on/off
- You can use plugins like I have installed for 80 character gutter and document overview (far right) with thumbnail slider
- The only caveat is you need to remember <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to quickly close the window to simulate `cat` which doesn't require keystrokes to close.