# How to use pygmentize automatically with less

Tags: syntax-highlighting, less

I found `pygmentize` thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/405970/41141), but it would be great if it could be used to highlight text with `less` or maybe replace the command.
Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was easier than I expected. I must to use:

```
export LESSOPEN='|pygmentize %s'
```

Comment: without the `-R` option, less probably won't show the colours, but the raw escape codes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course:

```
pygmentize -g /file/to/show | less -r
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't enough clear in my question, but I was expecting to replace `less` for `pygmentize`.Thanks anyway